# Active directory user alias

Tags: active-directory, alias, user-accounts

Do you know if exists something like "alias" for domain users? On my domain I have a short username (ex. n.surname) and i would like users could login with extended name (es. name.surname) to the same profile. Is it possibile?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is no such concept as an "alias", but you could use the `UPN (User Principal Name)` as login. The UPN is structured like an E-Mail address (`name.surname@domain.com`) and you can set/change it on the same tab as you can change the login name. Maybe that helps.